# What products should I use to add sound insulation to a party wall?

Tags: product-recommendation, sound-proofing

My bedroom shares a wall with my neighbours bathroom and I would like to add some sound proofing to my side of the wall. Can anyone recommend any particular products?

The wall is brick and does not have a cavity. Ideally I want to lose as little space as possible from my bedroom so adding a cavity to my side is not an option that I want to consider.

Answer (score 4):

You can get [acoustic plasterboard](http://www.soundservice.co.uk/acoustic_plasterboard.html) (UK site). It won't block out all the sound (as pointed out on the site) but will reduce it - hopefully to a more tolerable level.

Stick this to the wall and then skim/tile on top.

You will lose a bit of space from your room, but it's only one wall (the party wall).

Answer (score 4):

You are not going to get a significant amount of soundproofing without losing at least some space on your side.

From what you have described, it sounds like there is an exposed brick wall.  Adding some 1x2 or 2x2 framing and a layer of drywall will dramatically decrease the sound transfer.  In addition, adding insulation in the cavity will cut the noise even further.  All of this material together will only reduce the size of the room by 2 inches.

Answer (score 4):

[I am not an acoustic engineer]
There's no magic to sound-proofing - you need some "acoustically dense" material between you and sound (absorption), and some way to kill the vibration in the room (dampening).  Most of the ideas above are pretty reasonably for DIY.  You could build a home studio of acoustic tiles, but it will look funny and cost a lot. Expanding a bit on what was offered:

- Dampen the noise (stop the vibration): Double your drywall on any of the solutions above.  Use silicone (the green glue is a little better) on the studs/framing, and then in between your layers of drywall.
- Absorb the noise: If you have the space (and to be fair to your question, you probably don't have much), you can put something behind your drywall.  A nice product is [Roxul](http://www.roxul.com/home).  It isn't magic, but it's an improvement (as an added benefit, it's virtually fireproof).
- If you just want some good talk about soundproofing (grin), Holmes on Homes did an fun episode on this a while back.  A quick youtube search turned [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlAZsYp2M-U) up.

Answer (score 3):

I've read that a combination of density and elasticity are the best way to cut down sound. There is a product known as green glue which may help in your situation. It comes in large caulking tubes. It's applied between two layers of material, like drywall or plywood, and its elasticity supposedly helps cut the noise. If you search online for green glue you can find more technical specs and installation instructions.