# Soundproofing a partywall for airborne noises

Tags: walls, sound-proofing, noise-reduction

I need help soundproofing one of my bedroom walls, which is shared with the neighbors. Specifically I just want to reduce, as much as possible, chattering and loud talking sounds.

I own an apartment on the ground floor in an apartment building, I'm in Italy.

The condo is old, it was made in the early 1960s and probably no measure was taken for sound dampening when it was built.

Sound insulation is so not existing that when they talk loud enough I can distinguish each syllable they say even though the wall seems very thick.

This is a photo of the party wall from outside:

[image: party wall as seen from outside]

Any advice on how to proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/4076/18078 and https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/33371/18078 for starters.